# Specify az active subscription statically - IaC style

Tags: azure-cli, azure-bicep

Can az cli pick up the current subscription from a bicep file or a local "ansible.cfg" style config file? I don't want to set it from the cli, I want it to be picked up from some local definition.

Right now, the order of deployment commands I need to execute is:

```
cd ./staging
az login
az account set --subscription <id>
az deployment sub create ...
```

But `az account set --subscription <id>` is redundant, I already have subs/env separated by folders, so from whatever folder I am deploying I already know what sub I am using, it is statically defined:

staging/main.bicep

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

var subscriptionId = '00ta4479...'


module poc '../../../main.bicep' = {
  name: 'poc'
  scope: subscription(subscriptionId)
}
```

Comment: Your account could be linked to multiple tenants and subscriptions. By selecting the subscription you re making sure you re not creating a new subscription in another tenant. I think you could do the other way around `var subscriptionId = subscription().subscriptionId` ?

Comment: That is kind of my point, if all the IDs are hardcoded in the repo it would be impossible to make a mistake on the command line. I guess I'll have to rely on cli as the source of truth here.